# Read contents of xml elements as double

Tags: c#, xml

I want to create a List of objects from a data in an XML file.

```
public class Section //class description
{
   public string designation {get;set;}
   public double length {get;set;}
   public double crossSectionArea {get; set;}

   public Section CreateSection(string d,double l, double A)
   {
      return new Section
      {
         designation = d,
         length = l,
         crossSectionArea = A,
      };
    }

    Section(){}


}
```

the XML file looks like this

```
<Sections>
 <Section>
  <designation> Atx5E </designation>
  <length> 5.0 </length>
  <crossArea> 0.25 </crossArea>
 </Section>
 <!--- a lot of other Section elements with similar information!--->
</Sections>
```

I want to create a `List<Section>` using the data in the XML file i'm using XMLReader to get values from file.

```
static List<Section> LoadSections(string DataFile)//DataFile is string location of xml file
    {
        using (Stream stream = GetResourcesStream(DataFile))//returns a stream
        using (XmlReader xmlRdr = new XmlTextReader(stream))
            return
                (from SectionElem in XDocument.Load(xmlRdr).Element("Sections").Elements("Section")
                 select Section.CreateSection(
                    (string)SectionElem.Element("designation").Value,
                    (double)SectionElem.Element("length").Value,
                    (double)SectionElem.Element("crossArea").Value,
                 )).ToList();
    }
```

The method doesn't work and a FormatExeption was unhandled error. Is there a way to retrieve the contents of an element as a double? .Thats where i think the exception is being raised, when i try to read Element Contents as double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the `Value` property, just cast the elements directly.

```
static List<Section> LoadSections(string dataFile)
{
    using (var stream = GetResourcesStream(dataFile))
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
        return
            (from e in XDocument.Load(reader).Elements("Sections").Elements("Section")
             select Section.CreateSection(
                (string)e.Element("designation"),
                (double)e.Element("length"),
                (double)e.Element("crossArea")
             )).ToList();
}
```